# how to make a new tab and delete it by one vim.keymap.set command

Tags: neovim

I was trying to use lots of plugin in wsl-ubuntu and neovim to use it like an IDE to replace VScode.

I used NvimTree for file explorer and opened it, but when I used

```
:source
```

then the neovim terminal the NvimTree file exploring tab disappered, and I had to opened it again. Becaused it was annoying I tried to make a keymap like the code.

```
vim.keymap.set('n','<Leader>s',':tabnew source $MYVIMRC<CR> :q',{noremap=true})
```

Unfortunately, I don't works. Is there any idea to apply commands in a new tabs in vim.keymap.set() or a better method to solve my problem?